# Drupal not updating data for content page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6.19 to build a simple website with its own theme and layout. I also added and updated content regularly till I ran into a typical problem yesterday. There was a node-24 with a url alias of 'projects/india/current'. It is a content of type 'page'. As soon as I updated the content for this node, the data was not saved but it went to the url http://www.example.com/node/24/edit?destination=admin/content/node and the home page got displayed instead of normal update successful message. When I click on the back button I again came to the edit page options. It seems the data is not getting saved. I erased the body part of the content entirely and just typed 'test' and pressed the save button and to my surprise it updated successfully. I am not sure whats happening behind the hoods. I am using input format as PHP code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Lots of information, but a very difficult question to answer. This is more of a troubleshooting problem. I would start by looking at the PHP Filter code and make sure its good. PHP Filter is usually a bad idea, as it's harder to debug and can much more easily break your site.

Answer (score 0):

just check the node the data might have been saved. due to load on server at times this happens check your logs if you are getting ERROR 500 at times